# Wiring up Hapi / node.js & Postgresql in non-ORM enterprise scenario

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, architecture, hapi.js

I'm using Hapi to implement a backend for a angularJS-based web application providing access to non-trivial workflows.
The database behind the backend is postgresql. Because the data is also used by other components, I have limited control over the schema (I can add tables, views, columns etc., but I cannot restructure everything to fit an ORM). The workflows must be atomic, so I need to be able to do SELECT... FOR UPDATE to avoid transactionality / locking issues. Optimistic locking would also be an option, but doesn't seem necessary so far.

In my ideal world, there would be a hapi plugin providing
- generic reading of JavaScript objects from query results: I do a SELECT * FROM myview, I get a JavaScript object for every result row, and the columns have miraculously turned into fields
- a way to save me from worrying about parameter escaping - e.g. I do 'WHERE column=%s' and a parameter and it just works
- requests are automagically wrapped in pg transactions - and there is a hook to retry if the commit went wrong (especially for optimistic locking)

I have looked at all the nodejs and hapi modules/plugins I could find and that seemed relevant to the issue, but they all seem to either
- leave me having to worry about a lot of low-level stuff
- require me to deal with any errors at every single db call
- not support ALL pg features I might require (views, stored procedures - I don't really want to be limited to a subset of SQL)

But then - I lack practical experience with this scenario so far (though I've built plenty of backends with postgresql, usually in conjunction with either Java EE or python/django).

I like my business logic to deal with business logic - and not be interspersed with low-level stuff. These things should be separated in a clean architecture.

What is a good way to achieve that in the described scenario?

Comment: If you can limit yourself to PostgreSQL 9.3 or 9.4, look at PostgreSQL's row-to-json features

Comment: I can use PostgreSQL 9.3 - but have indeed not known about row_to_json. Thanks for the hint - while it won't solve the entire architectural issue, this will certainly make life easier.

Comment: See if you can get the ORM developers interested in supporting it, at least for 9.4 or 9.5 level json features. I'd love to see an ORM ask PostgreSQL "send me that as json" instead of doing giant chains of left joins.